# How to make R word cloud display most frequent term in lighter shade of color

Tags: r, word-cloud

I created a word cloud in R with the code:

```
wordcloud(words$term, words$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(32), scale=c(5, .5))
```

And it works fine only that it colors the terms in such a way that the most frequent appear in the darkest shade of the color and the least frequent in the lightest shade of the color. But I want it to be the other way round. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Its doable for sure but you may have to figure out most/least frquent in advance and make a binned variable that you apply a gradient to.  This blog post of mine is related and has everything you would need to do this but you'll have to do some leg work: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/gradient-word-clouds/

Comment: @TylerRinker nice blog will check it out thank you

Comment: If your words are ordered you can just use `rev` on your color vector.

Comment: @Victorp yes they are ordered but where do i put the `rev`? sorry i'm kinda new to this

Comment: Try : `wordcloud(words$term, words$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(32)), scale=c(5, .5))
`

Comment: @maryam @Victorp I added an example of `rev` which I tested in my solution.

Comment: @Victorp it works very well thanks a lot

Comment: @Victorp Hi I'm just experimenting with the code you posted before, this one: `colors=rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(32)[seq(8,32,6)])` i was wondering what is the function of the `seq(8,32,6)` and what does the last argument `6` do? thanks

Comment: It's for create a sequence of number from 8 to 32 by increment of 6. I add it to select certain color from `colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(32)`, precisely the 8th, 14th, 20th, 26th and 32e.

Comment: @Victorp oh, brilliant!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. You can specify non-random color assignment (`random.color = FALSE`) which will make it based on frequency then choose a value of `colors` using a palette that goes in the order you prefer.

For example, if `colors = "black"`, which is the default/example in the Vignette is the opposite of what you want, then choose `colors = "Pastel"` or some other scale that you prefer.

Personally, I use Color Brewer (`RColorBrewer`) with a **sequential pallete** to accomplish this:

```
pal = brewer.pal(9,"Blues")
wordcloud(words = d$word, 
          freq = d$freq, 
          scale = c(8,.3), 
          random.order = F,
          random.color = F,
          colors = pal)
```

Alternately, you could use `rev` on your color pallet, as @Victorp pointed out in the comments. Here's an example of that:

```
pal = brewer.pal(9,"BuGn")
wordcloud(words = d$word, 
          freq = d$freq, 
          scale = c(8,.3), 
          random.order = F,
          random.color = F,
          colors = rev(pal))
```

which gives you something like this:

[image: Word Cloud]

**Update:** I've written a blog article that covers this topic as well as the n-gram case and scraping data for your word clouds: http://hack-r.com/?p=35

Comment: Hi could you please demonstrate how to "use" the `rev`? thanks

Comment: @maryam It's there :) You might need to click refresh.

Comment: @NerdLife it definitely is there, thanks very much:)

Answer (score 3):

Another brilliant solution provided by Victorp in the comments section is to use the following as `color` argument:

```
colors=rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(32)[seq(8,32,6)])
```

Comment: If this is the best answer feel free to check it as correct for future searchers.

Comment: @TylerRinker I'll have to wait two days :s

Comment: @maryam "Blues" are already sequential, what's the extra bit of code at the end for?

Comment: @NerdLife Hi, yes "Blues" are sequential from lighter shades of blue to darker shades of blue. The `rev()` turns it the other way around, making it dark to light instead of light to dark. Finally the `seq()` is used to select the colors that are produced; in this case our palette produced 32 sequential colors and we used `[seq(8,32,6)]` to select from the 8th color in the palette to the 32nd color skipping 6 colors each time